# PDE solution - is my argument correct?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, harmonic-functions

**PROBLEM**

Let us consider the following Dirichlet Problem for the Laplace Equation:

$$
r^2 \partial_r^2(u) + r \partial_r(u) + \partial_{\theta}^2(u) = 0, \hspace{5mm} (r,\theta) \in ]0,1[ \times ]0, \pi/2[
$$
$$
u(1,\theta) = \sin(2\theta)^2, \hspace{5mm} \theta \in [0, \pi/2] 
$$
$$
u(r,0) = u(r,\pi/2) = 0, \hspace{5mm} r \in [0,1]
$$

**MY ATTEMPT**

We know that the solution to this problem, if it exists, is unique. Therefore we only need to find one function that satisfies both the boundary conditions and the equation to solve it. My idea was then to develop $u$ into a Fourier Series of sines and cosines with respect to the variable $\theta$ with fixed $r$, just as I would do if the problem was given on the whole unitary disk. However, in order for the second boundary condition to be satisfied, I decided to only keep the terms of the form $\sin(2n\theta), n\in \Bbb Z_+$:

$$
u(r,\theta) = \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}b_n r^{2n} \sin(2n\theta)
$$

Now, I only need to find the coordinates $b_n$ by using the first boundary conditions. To this purpose I developed $\sin(x)^2$ in a Fourier Series of sines in $[0,\pi]$ (this should be possible since I can extend the function to be odd in $[0,2\pi]$ with integrable derivative):

$$
\sin(x)^2 = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{\pi} \left( \frac{1}{(2n+1)+2} - \frac{2}{(2n+1)} + \frac{1}{(2n+1)-2} \right) \sin((2n+1)x), \hspace{5mm} x \in [0,\pi]
$$

(only the even terms survived when I solved the integrals for the coordinates).
Evaluating the equation for $x=2\theta$ we obtain an expression for $\sin(2\theta)^2$ (which I guess is just its Fourier Series of sines in $[0,\pi/2]$) which can be used to determine the $b_n$'s by comparison:

$$
b_{2(2n+1)} = \frac{1}{\pi} \left( \frac{1}{(2n+1)+2} - \frac{2}{(2n+1)} + \frac{1}{(2n+1)-2} \right), \hspace{5mm} n \in \Bbb N
$$
$$
b_n = 0 \hspace{5mm} \text{in all the other cases}
$$

**MY QUESTION**

I would like to know if the procedure and the solution are correct and wether my argument can be improved.

Comment: @Gonçalo I mean $(\sin(2\theta))^2$ (the whole sine squared). I am sorry if that caused any confusion.

Comment: I haven’t checked your method, but another method could be to extend $u$ to all of $B_1$ (the open unit ball in $\mathbb R^2$) by odd reflection then use the Poisson kernel

Comment: @JackT Actually, I am not so sure how you would extend $u$ by “odd reflection” because, thinking of the electrostatic equivalent, you have to make sure that the two segments in the first quadrant are at zero potential. However the odd reflection only does the job for the origin and the vertices on the circumference.

Comment: There is missing a sign, correct is

$$u(r,\theta)=-\frac{1}{\pi}{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(-\frac{2}{2 n+1}+\frac{1}{(2 n+1)+2}+\frac{1}{(2 n+1)-2}\right) r^{2 (2 n+1)} \sin (2 \theta  (2 n+1))}$$